# Multiple users buys last product at same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, e-commerce

I am creating an **ecommerce website using MERN** stack and suppose **there is a Product X which has 1 quantity left.**

Two users are buying the same product simultaneously. But the problem is that the quantity of the product is only 1.

**I have a solution** to lock the product for 10mins and reduce the quantity.

But if the user doesn't buy the product then for 10mins the product will be locked.

If there any other alternative solution?

Also if the solution discussed by me is optimal or not?

Comment: I am not sure how reserving the item is a solution to a concurrency problem. I think a reservation system simply moves the race condition from the purchase to the reservation. In any case, one solution is for the update to do the purchase could include a condition on the current quantity that the app observes. Such an update will fail if something else modifies the quantity at the "same time"

Comment: @user20042973 Okay but how will the API know if there are any failure? For example user adds a product and the quantity in decreased in the DB. Without purchasing the user exits the browser so in this case the quantity is 0 but the inventory still have 1 product left

Comment: My point isn't that you can't do a reservation system. Instead what I'm saying is that simply creating a reservation system doesn't necessarily solve the problem of two users trying to buy (now reserve) the same product. You'll still have to deal with concurrency, now just when reserving rather than buying. The 'handle failure's question is different too - but the app should always check the response from the database and take appropriate action. You'll have to do so anyway even if there's a reservation system as failures to update the product can still occur

Comment: That is true, then how the problem can be solved? As DB will return 1 quantity every time(till the purchase hasn't being made). Both the users are selecting the product together.

Answer (score 2):

When a user adds the product to their cart, instead of immediately reducing the quantity, you can reserve the product for 10 minutes.

If the user does not complete the purchase within the reservation period, release the reservation and make the product available again after 10 mins.

To implement this reservation system, you can utilize a combination of server-side and client-side logic. On the server side, you can track the reservation status of the product and handle the expiration of the reservation. On the client side, you can handle the user interface updates and interaction based on the reservation status.

By implementing a reservation system, you can provide a fair opportunity for users to purchase a limited quantity of products while ensuring that the product is not locked indefinitely if a user abandons the purchase process.

Comment: So how can I release the reservation after 10 mins? I mean how will the function(which have the code for releasing the reservation) execute after 10mins.

Comment: To release the reservation after 10 minutes, you can use the setTimeout function. The setTimeout function is used to schedule the execution of release Reservation after a specified delay. In this case, you can set the delay to 10 minutes by multiplying 10 (minutes) by 60 (seconds) by 1000 (milliseconds).

Comment: Okay, the setTimeout will run if the user closes the tab? Suppose the user closed the tab after 5 min of adding to reservation so will the setTimeout() function run after that as well? Also thankyou for your response.

Comment: Yes, you can use cron jobs from the server side to schedule tasks or actions to be executed at specific times or intervals, including scenarios where the user may have closed the tab.